# Flutter ScrollView Animation: How do you prevent scroll animation when children change size?

Tags: dart, flutter

When the bottom child is tapped (the height changes when its tapped), the parent color (blue) is shown while animating.

Is there anyway to prevent the animation?

Should I be thinking about this in a different way?

[image: Parent color shows on child size change]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Container(color: Colors.blue, child: CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
            TapBox(color: Colors.red),
            TapBox(color: Colors.white),
            TapBox(color: Colors.red),
          ]),
        )
      ],))
    );
  }
}

class TapBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color color;

  TapBox({ this.color });

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TapBoxState();
}

class _TapBoxState extends State<TapBox> {
  double height = 500;

  onTap() {
    setState(() {
      if (height == 500) {
        height = 250;
      } else {
        height = 500;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(child: InkWell(onTap: onTap, child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
              return Container(width: constraints.maxWidth, height: height, color: widget.color);
            })));
  }

}
```

Comment: You may need to refresh the page to get the GIF to start over 